# How can I get the whole number without rounding it off?

Tags: vb.net, math, decimal

This is the code:

```
Select Case Math.Truncate(n)
            Case 0
                Return ""

            Case 1 To 19
                Dim arr() As String = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
                  "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen",
                    "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"}
                Return arr(n - 1) & " "

            Case 20 To 99
                Dim arr() As String = {"Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"}
                Return arr(n \ 10 - 2) & " " & NumberToText(n Mod 10)

            Case 100 To 199
                Return "One Hundred " & NumberToText(n Mod 100)

            Case 200 To 999
                Return NumberToText(n \ 100) & "Hundred " & NumberToText(n Mod 100)

            Case 1000 To 1999
                Return "One Thousand " & NumberToText(n Mod 1000)

            Case 2000 To 999999
                Return NumberToText(n \ 1000) & "Thousand " & NumberToText(n Mod 1000)

            Case 1000000 To 1999999
                Return "One Million " & NumberToText(n Mod 1000000)

            Case 1000000 To 999999999
                Return NumberToText(n \ 1000000) & "Million " & NumberToText(n Mod 1000000)

            Case 1000000000 To 1999999999
                Return "One Billion " & NumberToText(n Mod 1000000000)

            Case Else
                Return NumberToText(n \ 1000000000) & "Billion " _
                  & NumberToText(n Mod 1000000000)
        End Select
```

So if the value of `**n as Decimal = 98.8**`, I should get Ninety-Eight. But instead what I'm getting is Ninety-Nine and my conclusion is it's rounding off. What supposed to be is the problem?

Comment: What you say is happening is not actually happening. There is something else in the code you chose not to show us that is responsible for that. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly, then we can see what you're actually doing wrong.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you think that `Math.Truncate` will change the value of the variable that you pass to it. That's not the case. What actually happens is that it returns the truncated value, so you have to use that return value, not the original value. The original value is still 99.8 so, if you force that into an `Integer` variable, it will be rounded to 100. That's just a guess though. If you show us your actual code, as you should have in the first place, then we can see for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(As @jmcilhinney already suspected in a comment):</sup>

You continue to use n (not truncated) under the case statements.
This is easy to debug by stepping through the code.
You'll see the second call with n=8.8, used in `arr(n-1)`, this is an implicit conversion to int, which uses rounding and leads to index 8 (= string `Nine`).